# Delphi - Grid não apresenta todos os campos da instrução SQL

Tags: sql, delphi, firedac, dbgrid

Faz dois dias que estou esquentando os miolos e não descubro o problema. Tenho uma instrução SQL (TFDQuery) escrita no código e que seleciona três campos de uma tabela para apresentá-los em um DBGrid. Não sei o que acontece. O terceiro campo nunca é mostrado. E se eu retido um dos dois campos que aparecem no DBGrid da instrução SQL, dá erro em tempo de execução, dizendo que está faltando o campo.

A instrução SQL está conforme abaixo:

Obs.: o DataSet é um TFDQuery. Quando comecei a usá-lo, escrevi a instrução abaixo diretamente na guia SQL Command do Query Editor do componente, porém sem o campo aluNascimento. Depois passei a escrever a instrução no código para execução em runtime e acrescentei o aluNascimento.

FormPesquisar.DataSet.SQL.Text := 'SELECT idAluno, aluNome, aluNascimento FROM Alunos WHERE aluNome LIKE :Nome';

O campo aluNascimento não aparece no DBGrid. E se eu removo o campo idAluno ou aluNome da instrução SQL, surge o erro em tempo de execução dizendo que o campo está faltando.

Alguém já passou por algo semelhante ?

Obrigado por qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Bom dia, veja no DFM do seu formulário onde está o dataset se há alguma referência persistente dos fields (no dataset ou no grid).  
Para ver o DFM pressione a tecla Alt + F12.

Comment: Olá Andrey. Obrigado pela sua resposta. No DFM do DataModule está conforme abaixo:

Comment: Bom dia, Andrey. VOCÊ ESTÁ CERTO !!!. Abri o DFM do DataModule e lá estavam constando os dois campos. Exclui o TFDQuery do DataModule, salvei e voltei a colocar outro componente TFDQuery com o mesmo "name". Rodei a aplicação e funcionou direitinho, inclusive já mostrando o terceiro campo. Muito obrigado, mesmo. Grande abraço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia, conforme comentado acima, é possível que hajam *fields* persistentes no *dataset*.. uma forma de conferir é verificar no DFM do seu formulário (onde está o *dataset*) se há alguma referência persistente dos *fields* (no *dataset* ou no grid).
Para ver o DFM pressione a tecla `Alt + F12`.
Caso os *fields* persistentes sejam constatados, basta removê-los (preferencialmente pelos meios normais, encontrando os *fields* visualmente).

Comment: Oi Andrey. Conforme comentado acima, você matou a charada e eu já corrigi o problema. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Há diversas possibilidades para o campo não aparecer. Entre elas:
1) O objeto de campo está invisível,
2) O dataset possui objetos de campo, mas não o desse campo especificamente (fields editor),
3) O dbgrid possui objetos de coluna, mas não a coluna desse campo específico.

Comment: Oi Ricardo. 1) Não estou deixando nenhuma columa invisível; 2) Não estou utilizando Fields Editor porque a quantidade de campos pode mudar; e 3) O DBGrid não possui nenhuma coluna definida através do Columns Editor (a quantidade de colunas aparece de acordo com a quantidade de campos do SQL). O estranho é que as duas primeiras colunas aparecem. Será que o SQL fica gravado em algum lugar ? Já que quando retiro um campo do SQL definido no código ele dá erro dizendo que falta aquele campo...

Comment: Mais uma possibilidade: veja a propriedade FieldDefs do Dataset. Se tiver objetos pode limpar tudo. Se não me engano, os campos são incluídos ali quando StoreDefs = True.

Comment: Olá Ricardo. O Andrey localizou o problema, conforme acima. Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda.